# Apple Developer Program

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I've been working at learning programming for a while now and I feel that I could benefit from becoming a paid member, and be able to test on device, however £59 for a year is little steep just to test on device, before I even think of going to the app store. 
Is it possible for a student in high school to get any discount (even £3) (I know that some companies offer software to students for free, so I thought this may apply to Apple and the iOS developer program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a [University developer program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/). It's explicitly for higher education institutions, but a representative of your school district might be able to convince Apple to let them join.  For everyone else, the price I've seen is $99/year.

Comment: Yep I meant to put £ rather than $. I doubt I'll be able to join the uni program seeing as I'm only in secondary/high school. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's worth it to ask your school admins to talk to Apple about signing up. Little investment on your part, great potential returns.